# How to get the list of all printers in computer in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to get all printers that are available in a system in angular code.

Comment: hello, have you any solution?

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot do this using only the front-end**. But you can implement this using your back-end. (You may use the 3rd party library [node-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/printer) to do this (NODE-JS).
In this library, there is a method called **getPrinters()** to get all printers.)

Anyway remember that, JS has a limited access to OS functions. So the best practice is to get all the information from the back-end. You can have a service (API) to get all printers.

Comment: thank you , and may I ask you how can I send a request to the printer after selecting the printer name?

Comment: There are a lots of tutorials for that. This one uses web socket https://medium.com/@yehandjoe/angular-2-raw-printing-service-56614d358754

Comment: This one uses printing mechanism supported in modern web browsers. You need to specify the printer using browser's print facility. https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/angular-print-service-290651c721f9

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have another question now,I want to change the default printer name(destination) when the user select one of the printers name in a combo box that I created in my code,I appreciate your help in advance.